# RakeTask returns "Don't know how to build task" in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task, rakefile

I am a newb and when running the below rake task keep getting the error message "Don't know how to build task 'create_postgis_template'".

My rake file looks as follows:

```
require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
require 'tasks/rails'

namespace :postgres do
  desc "create postgis db template on osx boxes"
  task :create_postgis_template do
    print "Enter your postgres username: "
    user = STDIN.gets
    user.chomp!
    root = File.dirname(__FILE__)
    cmd  = "psql -U #{user} -f assets/sql/postgis_template_osx.sql template1"
    system(cmd)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create_postgis_template` task is defined within the `postgres` namespace; so it would be called from `rake postgres:create_postgis_template` command, and not `rake create_postgis_template` command.

Best to run `rake -T` to see all the tasks available as `rake` tasks.

Comment: Awesome!thank you! This is my first time using postgres would you know how to create my user password?